# Opening of PowerPoint error for VBA

Tags: excel, object, runtime-error, powerpoint, vba

I have a script that creates a PowerPoint presentation by calling on macros that create a certain slide. However, for a part of the presentation I need to grab a slide from the last presentation and copy it into the new presentation. But when I open the presentation I get the error: Method 'Open' of object Presentations failed. How do I fix that?

```
Sub CreateNewPresentation()

  Dim ppApp As PowerPoint.Application
  Dim ppPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
  Dim slidesCount As Long

  On Error Resume Next
  Set ppApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
  On Error GoTo 0

  If ppApp Is Nothing Then
    Set ppApp = New PowerPoint.Application
  End If

  Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Add
  ppApp.Visible = True
  slidesCount = ppPres.Slides.Count
  Call create_Views_Slide(slidesCount, ppPres, ppApp)
End sub

sub create_Views_Slide(sldNum As Long, ppPrez As PowerPoint.Presentation, ppt As PowerPoint.Application)
  Dim myFilePath As String, myFileName As String, myFile As String
  Dim ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
  Dim objPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
  Set ppSlide = ppPrez.Slides.Add(sldNum + 1, ppLayoutBlank)
  ppPrez.PageSetup.SlideSize = ppSlideSizeLetterPaper
  myFile="File path....."
  Set objPres = ppt.Presentations.Open(myFile)
  objPres.Slides(1).Copy
  ppPrez.Slides.Paste Index:=1
  objPres.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

My string for File Path was wrong.